# Differences between factoring an equation and dividing one

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, factoring

I've been browsing the Math exchange for some time (as well as other sites) looking for an answer in regards to:

**"Are there any fundamental differences between factoring an equation, and dividing one?"**

I found a decent answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=differences%20between%20factoring%20and%20dividing%3F), but it fails to elaborate in depth on what these differing properties are.

For example, we can factor the equation

```
2x^2 + 4x - 8
```

By pulling out a 2, getting x^2 + 2x -4

However, is that fundamentally different in ***any way*** from

```
(2x^2 + 4x - 8)/2
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The question is rather more deep than you might expect. When you say something factors or not  depends on what type of number you are allowing. $2x+1$ does not factor over integers but does over rationals.

Comment: I see... so this may be a bigger 'rabbit hole'  than I thought

Comment: Maybe look at splitting fields for a detailed discussion.